# Is the jndi.properties file required for a EJB + web application (JBoss 5)?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi

In a JBoss 5 JEE project which I have inherited, the web application (WAR) project contains a JNDI configuration file which seems to be unneccessary. Its content is

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
```

Removing it has no obvious effect, deployment and execution works well and unit tests show no errors.

Is it safe to delete this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create that file if you want to create a -client- that connects to a JNDI context to invoke EJBs remotely. If that war is part of the application that serves the EJB, you indeed do not need it since you already have local access to the JNDI context. Assuming the war is part of an EAR that also holds the EJB module.